# Program which guesses a number

Tags: java, while-loop

Hi guys I'm writing a program which plays a guessing game with the user. You need to think of a number and the program will guess it. Here's my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 do 100 and i'll guess it");
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100;
        int guess = (max-min)/2 + min;
        boolean end = false;
        while(!end){

            System.out.println("zgaduje " + guess);
            String userInput = scan.next();
            if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("too much")){
                max = guess;
            }
            else if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("too small")){
                min=guess;
            }
            else if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("correct")){
                end = true;
            }
             guess = (max-min)/2 + min;
        }
    }
}
```

So the program guesses a number, and then based on the user input (too small or too much) it guesses again. It does not work as it supposed to, it only displays the first guess over again. Do you have any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: @Arnaud I dont think they are asking for numbers. They are saying "Think of a number." then printing a number and asking the user if they guessed correctly.

Comment: "Guess a number between 1 do 100 and i'll guess it" then min must be 1, not 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `scan.next();`. For input `too much`, that will return only `too`.

To read the whole line, you need to use `scan.nextLine();`

Comment: Yes that fixed my problem, I will accept Your answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should use NextLine instead of next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 do 100 and i'll guess it");
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100;
        int guess = (max-min)/2 + min;
        boolean end = false;
        while(!end){

            System.out.println("guess is" + guess);
            String userInput = scan.nextLine();
            if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("too much")){
                max = guess;
            }
            else if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("too small")){
                min=guess;
            }
            else if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("correct")){
                end = true;
            }
             guess = (max-min)/2 + min;
        }
    }
```